# How much diffraction happens when the size of the gap is less than the wavelength of the water wave?

Tags: waves

If a parallel water wave (water wave with straight wavefronts) is incident on a gap, diffraction happens. However, how much diffraction happens depends on the relative size of the gap to the wavelength of the water wave. The idea is, that a lot of diffraction happens (water wave spreads a lot) when the size of the gap and the wavelength of water wave are equal. If the gap size is bigger than the wavelength then the diffraction will be small (water wave doesn't spread that much). It is unclear to me what will happen if the gap size is smaller than the wavelength. Most textbooks say a small amount of water wave will pass in this case so the diffraction can be ignored or no diffraction happens at all. But if I start with a gap with a size comparable to the wavelength, and then I reduce its size a little bit, what will happen to the spreading angle of the diffracted water wave? Will the spreading angle be a little bit bigger or smaller? Does the same thing also happen for other waves like light and sound?

Comment: the "amount" of diffraction is the same but it is not the same *relative* to the undiffracted parts that is proportional to the width of the slot. if the wavelength is longer than the width you get the Huygens (hemi) spherical wavelet coming out, the narrower the width to closer to being a full hemi-sphere. yes it is the same for EM waves.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the statement "the "amount" of diffraction is the same but it is not the same relative to the undiffracted parts that is proportional to the width of the slot". Can you explain to me in terms of this statement, why the diffraction is largest when the wavelength and gap size are equal?

Comment: diffraction is an edge effect, wave hits the *edge* of an obstacle, the portion of the wave not adjacent to the edge and not obstructed passes, what hits the obstacle gets reflected, and what hits the edge gets diffracted, by "hitting" is meant all within *some* fraction (this is a bit fuzzy and other detail dependent) of a wavelength. When the slit is narrower than a wavelength then whatever passes is just an "edge effect" and it is diffracted. The narrower the opening is the more it resembles Huygens's ideal infinitesimal spherical (or cylindrical for a linear slot) wavelet.

Comment: the reason why it appears less of an effect if the slit is wider because the observational background that the unobstructed wave creates is larger as more of the wave goes through the slot. by edge effect is meant that the wave incident on the edge induces a secondary wave emitted by the edge itself. in the case of an EM wave the metallic edge will have an edge current induced on it that acts as an antenna radiating a secondary cylindrical or spherical wavelet, the diffracted wave,  that and is added to, superposed on, the undiffracted portion..